# Consuming Web Services in Oracle 10g pl\sql

Tags: oracle, web-services, plsql

I’m using soap_api method for accessing web services in Oracle. When I create add_numbers function and I execute add_numbers function then Function doesn’t execute. It fires following error when calling web service in select statement:

```
select add_numbers(2,5) from dual;
```

The error is :

```
ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed
ORA-06512: at "TEST.SOAP_API", line 178
ORA-06512: at "TEST.ADD_NUMBERS", line 40
```

I’m using this function and soap_api methods from this link. Taken example from

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/consuming-web-services-9i.php#Top

Function for calling web services.

```
FUNCTION add_numbers (p_int_1  IN  NUMBER,
                  p_int_2  IN  NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
l_request   soap_api.t_request;
l_response  soap_api.t_response;
l_return    VARCHAR2(32767);

l_url          VARCHAR2(32767);
l_namespace    VARCHAR2(32767);
l_method       VARCHAR2(32767);
l_soap_action  VARCHAR2(32767);
l_result_name  VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
l_url         := 'http://192.168.1.23:8080/TestWebservice.asmx';
l_namespace   := 'xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"';
l_method      := 'add';
l_soap_action := 'http://tempuri.org/add';
l_result_name := 'return';

l_request := soap_api.new_request(p_method       => l_method,
                                p_namespace    => l_namespace);

soap_api.add_parameter(p_request => l_request,
                     p_name    => 'int1',
                     p_type    => 'xsd:integer',
                     p_value   => p_int_1);

soap_api.add_parameter(p_request => l_request,
                     p_name    => 'int2',
                     p_type    => 'xsd:integer',
                     p_value   => p_int_2);

l_response := soap_api.invoke(p_request => l_request,
                            p_url     => l_url,
                            p_action  => l_soap_action);

l_return := soap_api.get_return_value(p_response  => l_response,
                                    p_name      => l_result_name,
                                    p_namespace => l_namespace);
RETURN l_return;

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all about the destination make sure that :

```
l_url         := 'http://192.168.1.23:8080/TestWebservice.asmx';
l_namespace   := 'xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"';
l_method      := 'add';
l_soap_action := 'http://tempuri.org/add';
l_result_name := 'return';
```

It is the same in WSDL XML FILE

Answer (score 0):

FUNCTION get_return_value in soap_api.sql is causing the issue.
open that sql file in package's body ..replace the FUNCTION get_return_value with below code .

```
FUNCTION get_return_value(p_response   IN OUT NOCOPY  t_response,
                          p_name       IN             VARCHAR2,
                          p_namespace  IN             VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN
  if p_response.doc.extract('//'||p_name||'/child::text()',p_namespace).getstringval() is not null then  
  RETURN p_response.doc.extract('//'||p_name||'/child::text()',p_namespace).getstringval();
  else return null;
END;
```